# App Store - App Privacy - Can't update app privacy questions (Admin)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

A few days ago I was able to submit my apps (no issues), but today, I got the following error:

> Before you can submit this app for review, an Admin must provide
> information about the app’s privacy practices in the App Privacy
> section. Learn more.

But there is no option to provide additional info in App Privacy section

[image]

I'm an admin. Can you please help with this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: How did you fix it? I have same problem right now and not sure what I can do :/

Answer (score 0):

How about to press the `Edit` on your provided image ?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/topic/select
Maybe contacting with apple about this issue will help.

Comment: Any solution to this? I have the exact same issue. 2 weeks ago, we submitted an app for review, and got approved, but we were not asked about this App Privacy thing. We already have url for privacy policy. But today, we are asked to do something to App Privacy which is not clear what to do. Thanks.